# Show Image in full screen as in Google Photos with Zoom in/out on imageView click

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a chat inbox which has image sharing functionality and **on ImageView click in the chat I want to show the image in full screen as in Google Photos with zoom-in and zoom-out functionality.** I have tried many things and codes but they are lacking and breaking somewhere.

As it's a normal use case, there must be some library or code snippet which provides all this functionality.

Can anyone suggest me some good resource or library for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the example in Google official documents. Maybe it'il help.

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom